# Combining IF and OR function with checkboxs to perform a calculation

Tags: excel

am trying to create an excel sheet with the following view

[image]

the idea behind it is when the user select check box marked with 10% to perform a direct 10% discount from the original amount and show the result in the final . ( which I managed succfully using the IF and precentage formula as the following.

```
=IF(E3,(C3-C3*$D$2),"no")
```

no I need to insert an OR function so it can calculate the new amount if a diffrent check box is selected or the "Other" filed is filled manually with the precentage .

in otherwords:

if
check box 1 checked
(deduct 10% from the Original Amount and show it in Final)
else
if
check box 2 checked
(deduct 20% from the original Amount and show it in final)
else
if
check box 1 is false and check box 2 is false and there is a value in Other-cell
(deduct the Other-cell value precentage from the original amount and show in in final).
else
(show the original amount as the final .

I started using the If and OR and got stuck

the formula I used as the following

```
=IF(OR(E3,(C3-C3*$D$2),c3),(G3,(C3-C3*$F$2),c3))
```

I am not an advance excel user tried to search the net but couldnt find somthing related is there a way to do so ?

as above

the formula I used as the following

```
=IF(OR(E3,(C3-C3*$D$2),c3),(G3,(C3-C3*$F$2),c3))
```

Comment: What about if both checks are marked? What about if both checkrs are marked and there is an input on `other`?

Comment: I will try to avoid that 
I modified the formula to this but the value came with two 00 added
=IF(E3,(C3-C3*$D$2),C3)*(IF(G3,(C3-C3*$F$2),C3))

so instead of 90 it showing 9000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following formula-

```
=IF(NOT(OR(E3,G3)),C3*H3,IF(E3,C3*D2,IF(G3,C3*F2,"Something Else")))
```

[image]

Comment: this worked but when am trying to copy the line or add more records to the list the checkboxes are not copied they will all still inked to the first check box what is what am doing wrong ? I mean the new check box is still linked to the old refernece

Comment: That is expected behavior of Excel. You need to change linked cell from checkbox property.

Answer (score 1):

The control flow concept I think you're trying to get at is if/else.

Your `IF` function already has an else clause `=IF(<condition>, <true case>, <false(else) case>)`, so what you can do is nest another if function in the else case. I'd recommend checking if the 20% box is ticked first, as if both are ticked, whichever is checked first will set the output.

`=IF(<20%>,<20% discount total>, IF(<10%>, <10% discount total>, <full total>))`

or

`=IF(G3, C3-C3*F2, IF(E3, C3-C3*D2, C3))`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below formula, it should work as you expect.

```
=IF(NOT(OR(E3,G3)),C3-C3*H3,IF(E3=TRUE,C3-C3*D2,C3-C3*F2))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).